# как исправить переход amason ses на tls 1.2?

Tags: email

на сайте настроена отправка почты через amazon ses используя ssmtp, т.к. amazon перешел на tls 1.2 то сообщения стали отбиваться с ошибкой, что TLC не соответствует 1.2, подскажите можно это исправить?

Comment: ssmtp какой версии на какой ОС?

Comment: debian 9 ssmtp/oldoldstable,now 2.64-8+b2